# Spring MVC defaultValue for Double

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to build a controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET}, value = "/users/detail/activities.do")
public View foo(@RequestParam(value = "userCash", defaultValue="0.0") Double userCash)
{
    System.out.println("foo userCash=" + userCash);
}
```

This works fine:

http://localhost/app/users/detail/activities.do?userCash=123&

but in this one userCash==null despite the default value

http://localhost/app/users/detail/activities.do?userCash=&

From some digging it seems like the first one works b/c of a Editor binding like this:

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(Double.class, new CustomNumberEditor(Double.class, false));
```

The trouble is that the second param (ie false) defines whether blank values are allowed. If i set that to true, than the system considers the blank input as valid so i get a null Double class.

If i set it to false then the system chokes on the blank input string with:

> org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException:
>   Failed to convert value of type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'double'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty
>   String

Does anyone know how to get the defaultValue to work for Doubles?

Comment: That sounds like a bug, or at least a reasonable request for enhancement to me. Have you considered opening a ticket in JIRA? http://jira.springframework.org

Answer (score 0):

Likely you'll have to use your own CustomEditor that would implement your conversion logic.

From the request point of view, the url like /activities.do?userCash=& mean that userCash param is actually a blank or empty string (hence the error you are seeing).